# Why is Illustrator exporting only what's inside the artboard?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, save

When I try to save an image with illustrator it only saves a part of the picture. So only the part of the picture that fits on the actual page gets so and everything that hangs off of the page just gets cut off. How can I change this setting?

Answer (score 5):

When you export to `.JPG` for example and you want to save all your artwork (inside and outside your Artboard) try when Exporting to uncheck `Use Artboards` beware that this method let you export all of your Artboads in one single `.JPG` file.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is best practice to keep everything that you want to print within the art board. You can change the size of your art board by clicking on the art board tool. [image]

Answer (score 1):

If you do not wish to change the size of your art board, you will need to shrink the image to fit within the art board boundaries. Do this by selecting the image with the black arrow, then drag on the outer points that appear. Press shift while dragging to constrain the image and keep its proportions correct.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saving the file as ai? As saving the file as an illustrator .eps allows all artwork on page/art board and outside of the pasteboard to be viewed when placed into a document.